# How to store string in a struct array?

Tags: c

How can you store a string in a struct array? My code gave me a segmentation fault when I try this. This also happens with the integer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
/* get the weight and the object */

struct term{
    char term[200]; // assume terms are not longer than 200
    double number;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct term *new[12];
    
    char word[13]= "hello world";
    int num =123;
    strcpy(new[0]->term,word);
    new[0]->number = num;


    char word2[20]= "hello new world";
    int num2 =123;
    strcpy(new[1]->term,word2);
    new[0]->number = num2;
}
```

Comment: new[0] is unintialized, so of course assigning to its properties is going to error. Please turn on compiler warnings, which would have caught this easily.

Comment: `new` is an array of pointers to `struct term`, not an array of `struct term`.

Comment: Should the last line be `new[1]->number`?

Comment: the first line in main is 'struct term *new[12];'

Comment: @jwdonahue when I erase the pointer it says 'expression must have a pointer type'

Comment: @beautifulworld That's an array of pointers. You never allocated memory for them to point to.

Comment: Use `new[0].term` to access struct members. The `->` is for dereferencing struct members through a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`struct term *new[12]` is an array of pointers, they are uninitialized, in order to store anything there you must make your pointers point to some valid memory location, either by allocating memory for them:

```
struct term *new[12];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    new[i] = malloc(sizeof **new);
}
```

Or by othewise assigning them valid `struct term` variables, ***i.e.***:

```
struct term st;
new[0] = &st;
```

Anyway, for such a small array, you could just use a fixed size array, ***i.e.*** `struct term new[12]`.

`malloc` is a heavy function that involves multiple system calls, if you can, you should avoid it.

For better understanding when and where you should use dynamic memory allocation take a look at these:

[When and why to use malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8800482/6865932)

[When do I need dynamic memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12161774/6865932)

---

There is another problem you should address in your code, `char word2[13] = "hello new world"` is ill formed, the string is too large for its container. It'll need space for at least 16 chars.

Use empty bounds when assigning strings, ***i.e.*** `char word2[] = "hello new world"`, the complier will deduce the needed size for the string, avoiding mistakes like these.

---

#### Footnote

`new` is a reserved keyword in C++, it's used to allocate memory and is the functional equivalent of C's `malloc`, though it is allowed in C, I would avoid using it to name a variable.

Comment: so you mean add something like this? 'struct term *new = malloc(12*sizeof(struct term));'

Comment: No, you've allocated the array of pointers on the stack already. It's the pointers you need to allocate with `new[0] = malloc(sizeof(struct term));`

Comment: @beautifulworld, for all the pointers, I edited my answer.

Comment: @anastaciu, or the OP can avoid all that hassle by simply declaring `struct term new[MAX_TERMS];` and then use dot to dereference them. I think the OP doesn't yet understand the difference between local and heap storage.

Comment: @jwdonahue, definitely, for such a small array it's much better.

Comment: @jwdonahue, *I think the OP doesn't yet understand the difference between local and heap storage*, let's fix that, at least, begin to.

Comment: I can add that name `new` is not good choice. It is better to change it.

Comment: @i486 for sure.